# number of increasing 100 sized sequences of even numbers between 0 and 200

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of sequences $(a_1,\cdots,a_{100})$ where all $a_i$'s are even numbers which forms $0\leq a_1 \leq \cdots \leq a_{100} \leq 200$.

I know that the number of strictly incremental sequences of length $K$ with elements from $\{1, 2,\cdots,N\}$ is ${N}\choose{K}$. However, here the sequence is not strictly increasing sequence, hence the same answer should not be valid. The answer to my question is ${200}\choose{100}$, which feels weird to me because there are a lot more options for us to pick the sequences because it is not strictly increasing, however this is the same answer as the ${N}\choose{K}$ from the strictly increasing sequences.

Why the solution for both problems are the same?

Comment: "*which feels weird to me because there are a lot more options for us to pick the sequences because it is not strictly increasing*", but in this question you are only picking from the even numbers, and there are only $101$ even numbers in $0\le a \le 200$.

Comment: Just because things look the same, doesn't necessarily mean that they are the same. And if they are numerically equal, sometimes there could be a bijection between the two of them.

Comment: Divide each term by $2$, $\left(\frac {a_i}2\right)_{i=1}^{100}$ is a non-decreasing sequence of (even or odd) integers satisfying

$$0 \le \frac{a_1}2 \le \frac{a_2}2 \le\ldots\le \frac{a_{100}}2\le 100.$$

Increase each term by its index $i$, $\left(\frac {a_i}2 + i\right)_{i=1}^{100}$ is a strictly incremental sequence of integers satisfying

$$0<\frac{a_1}2+1<\frac{a_2}2+2<\ldots<\frac{a_{100}}2+100 < 201.$$

This shows one way of the bijection.